# Rotate my SceneKit material

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm taking images with `AVCapturePhotoOutput` and then using their JPEG representation as the texture on a SceneKit `SCNPlane` that is the same aspect ratio as the image:

```
let image = UIImage(data: dataImage!)
let rectangle = SCNPlane(width:9, height:12)
let rectmaterial = SCNMaterial()
rectmaterial.diffuse.contents = image
rectmaterial.isDoubleSided = true
rectangle.materials = [rectmaterial]
let rectnode = SCNNode(geometry: rectangle)
let pos = sceneSpacePosition(inFrontOf: self.pictCamera, atDistance: 16.5)  // 16.5 is arbitrary, but makes the rectangle the same size as the camera
rectnode.position = pos
rectnode.orientation = self.pictCamera.orientation
pictView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(rectnode)
```

`sceneSpacePosition` is a bit of code that [can be found here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029347/position-a-scenekit-object-in-front-of-scncameras-current-orientation) that maps CoreMotion into SceneKit orientation. It is used to place the rectangle, which does indeed appear at the right location with the right size. All very cool.

The problem is that the image is rotated 90 degrees to the rectangle. So I did the obvious:

```
rectmaterial.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
```

This does not work property; the resulting image is unrecognizable. It appears that one small part of the image has been stretched to a huge size. I thought it might be the axis, but I tried all three with the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SceneKit but could it be that the image(texture) is not rotated on its center but on one of its corners and, unless your image is a perfect square, it could be rendered with stretching/tiling once rotated which could give strange results ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are rotating on the upper left corner as suggested by Alain T.
If you move your image down, you may get the rotation you were expecting.

Try this:

```
let translation = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -1, 0)
let rotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
let transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(translation, rotation)
rectmaterial.diffuse.contentsTransform = transform
```

Comment: I implemented this and found that the image was upside down - the correct rotation would be -pi/2 . So I changed the rotation to -pi/2, at which point it was off in space again.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to edit the previous message but took to long. After thinking about it a bit I saw the issue - the translation is -1,0,0 in that case. It's working, thank you!

Comment: For anyone trying to do this on an Apple Silicon M1, this causes a crash. Please report through Feedback Assistant.

A workaround that worked for me was to not do the translation, but just set the transform to the rotation as shown above.

Comment: Very interesting... has this been fixed with M1? I've been wondering about how compatible SceneKit. Are you not able reproduce the error on non-M1 devices? I assuming you were using an M1 iPad, or was this for macOS?

Comment: I am using an M1 and I am having several issues with SceneKit.