# How do you attach an object to your camera position with ARKit Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

I have moving objects which I want to have be able to collide with me the player. I have the ability to launch objects from me by getting my current position/direction at that time, but I do not understand how to attach an object to me which will follow my positioning at all times.

Comment: Which display technology are you using with ARKit? SceneKit? SpriteKit? Unity? Etc...

Comment: I am using SceneKit as my display technology.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In SceneKit, everything that can have a position in the scene is (attached to) a node. That includes not just visible objects, but also light sources and cameras. When you use `ARSCNView`, there's still a SceneKit camera, but ARKit controls its position/orientation.

SceneKit nodes create a hierarchy: every node's position (and orientation etc) are relative to its parent node. If the parent node moves within the scene, its children move along with it so that they keep the same parent-relative positions. So, if you want something to always keep the same position relative to the camera, you should make that content a child of the camera node.

Even in scenes where you don't create a camera yourself — such as when SceneKit and ARKit manage the camera for you — you can get the node containing the current camera with the view's [`pointOfView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523982-pointofview) property. (Note: `ARSCNView` is a subclass of `SCNView`, most of whose useful API is defined by the [`SCNSceneRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer) protocol.)

You may have to wait until the session starts running to access the ARKit-managed camera node.

Answer (score 19):

ARSCNView has a property 'pointOfView'. You can attach a child node to it.

```
let ball = SCNSphere(radius: 0.02)
ballNode = SCNNode(geometry: ball)
ballNode?.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -0.2)
sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(ballNode!)
```

The node will follow your camera anywhere you go.

Comment: This is useful if you want to add the object to the camera's node hierarchy, but if one wants to add it to the standard sceneView's node hierarchy, then I recommend this approach to have an SCNNode always in front of the camera: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029347/position-a-scenekit-object-in-front-of-scncameras-current-orientation/42030679#42030679

Comment: I just couldn't get this working: sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(...) - it shows nothing to me.

Comment: You need to give the ball a color or texture, then you will see it.

Answer (score 1):

Following code work for me to get the current position(x,y,z coordinates) of the camera.

```
    let pov = sceneView.pointOfView
    let position = pov?.position

    let x = position?.x
    let y = position?.y
    let z = position?.z
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take Jimi's answer and give the ball a color or texture to see it:

```
let ball = SCNSphere(radius: 0.02)
ball.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
let ballNode = SCNNode(geometry: ball)
ballNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -0.2)
self.sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(ballNode)
```