# SceneKit – Get direction of camera

Tags: swift, camera, scenekit, direction, arkit

I need to find out which direction a camera is looking at, e.g. if it is looking towards `Z+`, `Z-`, `X+`, or `X-`.

I've tried using `eulerAngles`, but the range for yaw goes `0` -> `90` -> `0` -> `-90` -> `0` which means I can only detect if the camera is looking towards `Z` or `X`, not if it's looking towards the positive or negative directions of those axes.

Comment: you do a dot product to do this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create an SCNNode that place it in worldFront property to get a vector with the x, y, and z direction.

Another way you could do it is like how this project did it:

```
// Credit to https://github.com/farice/ARShooter

func getUserVector() -> (SCNVector3, SCNVector3) { // (direction, position)
        if let frame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame {
            let mat = SCNMatrix4(frame.camera.transform) // 4x4 transform matrix describing camera in world space
            let dir = SCNVector3(-1 * mat.m31, -1 * mat.m32, -1 * mat.m33) // orientation of camera in world space
            let pos = SCNVector3(mat.m41, mat.m42, mat.m43) // location of camera in world space

            return (dir, pos)
        }
        return (SCNVector3(0, 0, -1), SCNVector3(0, 0, -0.2))
    }
```

Comment: Also, this is assuming that you are using ARKit, as your tag suggests

Comment: I didn't catch how can I know the direction after calculating "dir" ??