# ARKit create node from screen pan

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, arkit

I am currently working on an app where the goal is for the user to be able to swipe their finger on the screen and see a line of 3D objects in the scene, similar to 3D drawing. I have my scene setup with the gesture recognizer but I do not know how to create a node in 3D space based on the pan on the screen. This is all I have right now for my gesture recognizer.

```
`@IBAction func panRecognized(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Panning")
    print(sender.location(in: self.view).x)
    print(sender.location(in: self.view).y)
}`
```

What I am wondering is how can I create a node in 3D space with those x and y coordinates while also using the orientation and position of the device? The goal is the object to be placed about half a meter away from the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways that you can achieve this, although please note that this is just a starting point, and isn't optimised in anyway:

The first thing you would do is create a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in viewDidLoad for example e.g:

```
let panToDrawGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(createNodesFromPan(_:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panToDrawGesture)
```

To make it a bit more fun, also add an array of [UIColor] e.g:

```
let colours: [UIColor] = [.red, .green, .cyan, .orange, .purple]
```

Then to draw using your gestureRecognizer you can do something like this:

```
///Creates An SCNNode At The Touch Location Of The Gesture Recognizer
@objc func createNodesFromPan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    //1. Get The Current Touch Location
    let currentTouchPoint = gesture.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView)

    //2. Perform An ARHitTest For Detected Feature Points
    guard let featurePointHitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, types: .featurePoint).first else { return }

    //3. Get The World Coordinates
    let worldCoordinates = featurePointHitTest.worldTransform

    //4. Create An SCNNode With An SCNSphere Geeomtery
    let sphereNode = SCNNode()
    let sphereNodeGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.005)

    //5. Generate A Random Colour For The Node's Geometry
    let randomColour = colours[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colours.count)))]
    sphereNodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = randomColour
    sphereNode.geometry = sphereNodeGeometry

    //6. Position & Add It To The Scene Hierachy
    sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(worldCoordinates.columns.3.x,  worldCoordinates.columns.3.y,  worldCoordinates.columns.3.z)
    self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
}
```

Alternatively instead of using a gestureRecognizer you could use touches to perform you drawing:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    //1. Get The Current Touch Location
    guard let currentTouchPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView),
        //2. Perform An ARHitTest For Detected Feature Points
        let featurePointHitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, types: .featurePoint).first else { return }

    //3. Get The World Coordinates
    let worldCoordinates = featurePointHitTest.worldTransform

    //4. Create An SCNNode With An SCNSphere Geeomtery
    let sphereNode = SCNNode()
    let sphereNodeGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.005)

    //5. Generate A Random Colour For The Node's Geometry
    let randomColour = colours[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colours.count)))]
    sphereNodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = randomColour
    sphereNode.geometry = sphereNodeGeometry

    //6. Position & Add It To The Scene Hierachy
    sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(worldCoordinates.columns.3.x,  worldCoordinates.columns.3.y,  worldCoordinates.columns.3.z)
    self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

}
```

In my example augmentedRealityView refers to an ARSCNView e.g:

```
@IBOutlet weak var augmentedRealityView: ARSCNView!
```

Hope it helps...

Update:

If you want to draw at a set distance, and only using the position of the ARCamera you can do something like this using the `ARSessionDelegate`(and if you want your drawing to be say 1m away from the camera then change the Z value of the sphereNode.position in part 3):

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

    //1. Create An SCNNode With An SCNSphere Geeomtery
    let sphereNode = SCNNode()
    let sphereNodeGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.01)

    //2. Generate A Random Colour For The Node's Geometry
    let randomColour = colours[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colours.count)))]
    sphereNodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = randomColour
    sphereNode.geometry = sphereNodeGeometry

    //3. Position & Add It To The Scene Hierachy
    sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(0,  0, -0.5)
    updatePositionAndOrientationOf(sphereNode, withPosition: sphereNode.position, relativeTo: self.augmentedRealityView.pointOfView!)
    self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
}


/// Updates The Position Of An SCNNode In Relation To The Camera Node
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - node: SCNNode
///   - position: SCNVector3
///   - referenceNode: SCNNode
func updatePositionAndOrientationOf(_ node: SCNNode, withPosition position: SCNVector3, relativeTo referenceNode: SCNNode) {

    /* Full Credit To Pablo
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029347/position-a-scenekit-object-in-front-of-scncameras-current-orientation/42030679
    */

    let referenceNodeTransform = matrix_float4x4(referenceNode.transform)

    // Create A Translation Matrix With The Desired Position
    var translationMatrix = matrix_identity_float4x4
    translationMatrix.columns.3.x = position.x
    translationMatrix.columns.3.y = position.y
    translationMatrix.columns.3.z = position.z

    // Multiply The Configured Translation With The ReferenceNode's Transform
    let updatedTransform = matrix_multiply(referenceNodeTransform, translationMatrix)
    node.transform = SCNMatrix4(updatedTransform)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: One question... Do you know how I can make it a fixed distance from the sceneCamera (aka the device)?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what to do here. Adding this code ends up with none of the spheres showing up, and I have tried playing around with some things to make it work but with no success. Can you give me a little pointer as to what I need add where? Thanks.