# ARKit SCNNode always in the center when camera move

Tags: swift, arkit

I am working on a project where I have to place a green dot to be always in the center even when we rotate the camera in ARKit. I am using ARSCNView and I have added the node so far everything is good. Now I know I need to modify the position of the node in

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)
```

But I have no idea how to do that. I saw some example which was close to what I have but it does not run as it suppose to.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    let location = sceneView.center
    let hitTest = sceneView.hitTest(location, types: .featurePoint)
    
    if hitTest.isEmpty {
        print("No Plane Detected")
        return
    } else {
        
        let columns = hitTest.first?.worldTransform.columns.3
        
        let position = SCNVector3(x: columns!.x, y: columns!.y, z: columns!.z)
        
        var node = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "CenterShip", recursively: false) ?? nil
        if node == nil {
            let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
            node = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: false)
            node?.opacity = 0.7
            let columns = hitTest.first?.worldTransform.columns.3
            node!.name = "CenterShip"
            node!.position = SCNVector3(x: columns!.x, y: columns!.y, z: columns!.z)
            sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node!)
        }
        let position2 = node?.position
        
        if position == position2! {
            return
        } else {
            //action
            let action = SCNAction.move(to: position, duration: 0.1)
            node?.runAction(action)
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter how I rotate the camera this dot must be in the middle.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but I assume its one of the following:

A) Place the green dot centered in front of the camera *at a fixed distance*, eg. always exactly 1 meter in front of the camera.

B) Place the green dot centered in front of the camera *at the depth of the nearest detected plane*, i.e. using the results of a raycast from the mid point of the ARSCNView

I would have assumed A, but your example code is using (now deprecated) `sceneView.hitTest()` function which in this case would give you the depth of whatever is behind the pixel at `sceneView.center`

Anyway here's both:

### Fixed Depth Solution

This is pretty straightforward, though there are few options. The simplest is to make the green dot a child node of the scene's camera node, and give it position with a negative `z` value, since `z` increases as a position moves *toward* the camera.

```
cameraNode.addChildNode(textNode)
textNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -1)
```

As the camera moves, so too will its child nodes. More details in this [very thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029347/position-a-scenekit-object-in-front-of-scncameras-current-orientation)

### Scene Depth Solution

To determine the estimated depth behind a pixel, you should use [ARSession.raycast](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/3132065-raycast) instead of [SceneView.hitTest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2875544-hittest), because the latter is definitely deprecated.

Note that, if the `raycast()` (or still `hitTest()`) methods return an empty result set (not uncommon given the complexity of scene estimation going on in ARKit), you won't have a position to update the node and this it might not be directly centered in every frame. To handle this is a bit more complex, as you'd need decide exactly what you want to do in that case.

The `SCNAction` is unnecessary and potentially causing problems. These delegate methods run 60fps, so simply updating the position directly will produce smooth results.

Adapting and simplifying the code you posted:

```
func createCenterShipNode() -> SCNNode {
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
    let node = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: false)
    node!.opacity = 0.7
    node!.name = "CenterShip"
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node!)
    return node!
}

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    // Check the docs for what the different raycast query parameters mean, but these
    // give you the depth of anything ARKit has detected
    guard let query = sceneView.raycastQuery(from: sceneView.center, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any) else {
        return
    }
    
    let results = session.raycast(query)
    if let hit = results.first {
        let node = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "CenterShip", recursively: false) ?? createCenterShipNode()
        let pos = hit.worldTransform.columns.3
        node.simdPosition = simd_float3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z)
    }
}
```

See also: [ARRaycastQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arraycastquery)

One last note - you generally don't want to do scene manipulation within this delegate method. It runs on a different thread than the Scenekit rendering thread, and SceneKit is very thread sensitive. This will likely work fine, but beyond adding or moving a node will certainly cause crashes from time to time. You'd ideally want to store the new position, and then update the actual scene contents from within the `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)` delegate method.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. The idea is when I put the VR glasses I dont have access to the phone anymore and if I want to click on some button (Node) and perform an action I need to focus on this button wait for a 2-3 seconds and it will make a click. I already did that but I need this centered node to indicate the user where he is pointing.